# CentOS7 firewalld no zones

Tags: vps, centos7, firewalld

I have installed firewalld on a fresh CentOS 7 minnimal installation on a VPS (weirdly enough, from what I've been searching firewalld should already be installed with system).

I tried opening some ports but when running a command like

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent`

I get following error message: `Error: INVALID_ZONE: public`.

When viewing available zones with `firewall-cmd --get-zones` i get nothing.

How should it be configured?

Comment: Is firewalld running? Try reinstalling it. Did you create any zones? Did your VPS provider delete them?

Comment: It is running, reinstalled it, nothing changed. I didn't create any zones, couldn't find a proper instruction on how to do it anywhere. Shouldn't there be some defaults with installation? Everywhere I looked it says that the firewall should already be installed with the system but it was not.

Comment: Have exactly the same problem, on a pi install of Centos 7 (RedSleeve 7). It seems to act like it simply hasn't loaded the zones files.

Comment: `firewall-cmd --new-zone=public` might help you create the zone, but then you should make sure it's the same as the public zone created by default

Comment: Are there any zones (xml files) in /usr/lib/firewalld/zones ?

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with your install. Maybe the disk is/was full?  Pre-defined zone XML files should be in the /usr/lib/firewalld/zones/ directory. The file /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf contains the DefaultZone entry. The active zone(s) should be in the /etc/firewalld/zones/ directory.  The firewall-cmd man page is easy to understand, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a pretty strange VPS setup and issue, but you can build your own zones easily enough if you don't mind writing a bit of XML.

My public zone is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone target="DROP">
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="443"/>

</zone>
```

It is a lightly modified version of the default public.xml, which drops instead of rejects packets, and allows HTTPS as well as SSH.

You would put this in (I think) /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml.

Answer (score 0):

VPSes do all sorts of dumb things. Some of them nuke SELinux on the kernel level, so that you can't even enable it. First of all, you want to check your kernel with `uname -r`. It should say `el7`, e.g.

```
3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
```

If it is el7, you're good. If not, you need to check with your VPS if you can use the stock EL kernels, or reinstall your instance from your own CentOS ISO (that's what I did on Vultr). It may still be possible to fix firewalld with a custom kernel, but it's better to have the official ones.

Anyway, if firewalld is actually functional, just not having zones, simply create the zone and add the services.

```
firewall-cmd --new-zone=public --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=ssh --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Note: you must do these in the same session, otherwise you may get locked out of SSH and resort to console access to fix your firewall.